# How to reboot to boot menu? 20.04.2

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, reboot

My keyboard has an issue where it does not work on startup which means I cannot access the boot menu. Is there a command to reboot and open straight to the boot menu? I'm assuming its something like this command as it opens the bios menu but not the drive select menu.

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

Comment: If you're able to access the UEFI firmware settings (BIOS hasn't been used for more than 10 years) then you can re-enable legacy USB support and disable Fast Boot, one or the other is what's preventing the keyboard to work before the OS loads.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by BIOS not being used for 10 years, when I run that command it definitely opens up the bios, I have an MSI motherboard and I have legacy usb support enabled and fast boot disabled, when I use a ps2 keyboard it works so I know that its the usb keyboard causing the issue. I was hoping there was an easy command like that one to just reboot straight to the drive select.

Comment: @chalkfish how many drives you have? Instead of firmware setup are you looking to select which drive to boot?

Comment: @UnKNOWn yes thats exactly what I want, but I cant access the boot menu so I was hoping there was a command.

Comment: what is the key that takes you to the drives selection menu? or what is the motherboard model or laptop model?

Comment: @UnKNOWn F11 and it is a MSI B350M

Comment: Ok. I think there is no way to get the menu you are looking for. I am thinking if there is a setting within the vendors config to choose drives menu as default. I will go through MSI B350M manual.

Comment: Have you gone through `efibootmgr` ??

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thank you! `efibootmgr --bootnext XXXX` worked perfect!

Comment: @UnKNOWn if you respond with that as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: @chalkfish write the answer what resolved your requirement. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `efibootmgr` will list your current drives.
Then run `efibootmgr --bootnext XXXX` with the id of the drive you want to boot with, once you restart it will boot with your selected drive.

Thank you [UnKNOWn](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/unknown)!

Answer (score 0):

Use an USB to PS2 adapter, The USB keyboard will work on PS2.

Edit---->
My newly ASUS motherboard has a combo PS2 Keyboard Mouse connection(for which I have a split PS2 adapter for keyboard and mouse). PS2 is not available only for old motherboards, as PS2 is a good and not to die soon standard.

Comment: While this may work for some (probably quite old) machines which only allowed the use of PS2 keyboards in BIOS menus, we don't even know if OP's machine has PS2 ports.

Comment: I can confirm it does work with my ps2 keyboard so I think I will have to buy an adapter, I was hoping there was just a command that would save me from that.